# How to access "this" context (Vue/Nuxt instance) in a VanillaJS file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a function inside a `.js` file in a nuxt 2 project.

Basically I need to use a nuxt module property from `nuxt.config` like this `this.nuxt.options.` inside a function in a normal `.js` file.

For example:

`aNormalJsFile.js`

```js
if (this.nuxt.options.module.triggers.isActive) {
  // do something
}
```

But now I can't because it doesn't know what is Nuxt of course. I'm getting this error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nuxt')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to inject a Vue/Nuxt instance inside of a `.js` file (vanilla JS), you can follow this helper function approach

`/src/utils/printCoolNumber.js`

```js
export const printIt = (VueInstance) => console.log(VueInstance.coolNumber)
// ☝ basically does console.log(this.coolNumber) as in a .vue file
```

Any `.vue` file

```html
<script>
import { printIt } from "@/utils/printCoolNumber";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      coolNumber: 12,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    printIt(this) //  Vue instance ("this") passed here, it prints 12 in the console
  },
};
</script>
```

I wouldn't say that this is the best approach in the long run ([using Composables](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html) is usually still better) but it is great for small helper functions where you don't need too much Vue-specific methods.

Comment: Passing the whole instance is an antipattern. If it's known which data is expected, only coolNumber needs to be passed

Comment: @EstusFlask agreed that it's not the best approach and that the example here is quite simple. Meanwhile, people still sometimes want to use `this` in their `.js` file and cannot migrate towards using Composition API. Nowadays it's baked into Vue2 but still, my solution is viable even if subpar on several aspects in comparison to a Composable approach.

Comment: For mixin-like approach, binding can do the same, `printIt.apply(this)`. This requires to have regular function (not arrow) aNormalJsFile.js any way