# Using Nuxt context inside custom js class

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm new in Nuxt, Vue and JS at all. So I can't understand how exactly imports and exports works in JS, what is it about contexts and more..

So I have a class (~/helpers/foo.js)

```
export default class Foo {
  static bar () {
    console.log(this.$nuxt); // or this.$config, this.$nuxt.$config or smth
  }
}
```

and in some component I called this function and got (it correctly imported and working) and got "undefined" in console on this console.log

Can someone explain me, how this is working? How can I pass the Nuxt's context to my class (if I can)? Should I define my class as a plugin for Nuxt (and rewrite it to single function 'cos Nuxt's plugins should be a fn? Class in my case used as a namespace for some functions, that is used for ab-testing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if you're new to JS, you should not be using Vue. Even less Nuxt, learn the basics and come back. You'll get a far easier time debugging and learning overall.
Skipping steps will not good in the mid/long term.

As for your question, you don't need to use Classes overall, especially for what you showed.

You can use the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74312538/8816585) to have both a successful export + import and the usage of Vue/Nuxt's context in a `.js` file.   Reading the [export page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) from MDN can also help quite a lot.

Comment: thanks for your response, forwarding 'this' is working. Thought it's not the best option to do it and ask my question 'cos thinking that there is a better way to do it with some imports or define my helper as a plugin. Why do you think I don't need Classes? I came to JS from PHP, where we are using OOP principles to organize common props and funcs to one class, why can't I do it in JS?

Comment: @Moonrage there is no better option tbh. Using [a mixin](https://vuejs.org/api/options-composition.html#mixins) is also not recommended because of the lack of explicitness and side effects. Defining it as a plugin will make it "better", it will change a local helper into a global one. A local is actually better IMO. Nuxt v3 comes with [the composables](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/composables#composables-directory) principle using the Composition API, by far the best option. You can do the same in JS for sure but OOP is mainly not needed hence why I say that it is not needed

Comment: @Moonrage I do understand the usage of OOP for games or some object-heavy things but for day-to-day web usage, I feel that it's not needed in a JS frontend ecosystem. At least, I never **had** to use it and most of the documentations/examples are never done in that way. So I'd say keep it simple and use the shorter/most direct JS implementation available for a given use-case.

Comment: ok, I got you, thanks a lot!