# Pass variable from .vue to .js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is it a way to pass a variable in my .vue to a .js function that it import? How can I pass the `cur_page` variable to `'@/js/enquiry.js'`?

page.vue:

```
<template>
 <custom-page v-if="tableReady" 
      :current_page="cur_page"  <-- the var I want to pass-->
       v-on:changePage="changePage"/>
</template>

<script>
import dataRen from '@/js/enquiry.js'// the js file that I want to pass the var to

export default {
data() {
      return {
          cur_page:1,
      },
      methods: {
        drawBettingEnquiryTable() {
        let cols = '';
        var pageTotal ='';
        
        cols = dataRen.betting_header(this.lang);
        this.enquiryTable =  $('#js-table').DataTable({
           columns: cols,
        })
        }
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

---

Comment: have you tried import/export instead of require? require wont work in browser mode.

Comment: You can't really pass variables to "files". You'd pass values to functions from that file when you call them…!?

Comment: @Anis you're right, I think I should tried import

Comment: Does that one help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74312538/8816585

Comment: @kissu yes,that one help